# GCC over-optimizing? Different number of seconds since the start of an epoch depending on where I compile

Tags: c, optimization, gcc

**Backstory:** I have a problem with time conversion, which I was trying to solve. The program I'm working on uses internal date representation. The date is represented as a number of seconds since 2000/01/01. That number is constant in a program. My guess was, that it shouldn't be, since that number might depend on the timezone.

I made a simple program, to test if number of seconds since unix epoch start for 2000/01/01 differs on different machines:

```
struct tm tm_date;
time_t t_LongDate;

tm_date.tm_year = 2000 - 1900;
tm_date.tm_mon  = 1 - 1;
tm_date.tm_mday = 1;
tm_date.tm_hour = 0;
tm_date.tm_min  = 0;
tm_date.tm_sec  = 0;

t_LongDate = mktime(&tm_date);
printf("result: %lld\n", (long long)t_LongDate);

return 0;
```

I compiled the program on my development machine, and it seemed to work:

`result: 946681200`

Then I uploaded the binary to the problematic host. That disproved my hypothesis. The number of seconds was the same:

```
problematic-host# ./a.out 
result: 946681200
```

Because I'm a suspicious person, I tried recompiling the program on the problematic-host. Haven't expected much, but:

```
problematic-host# gcc secSinceEpoch.c 
problematic-host# ./a.out 
result: 946677600
```

As I initially expected - there's hour of difference. But what happened? Has GCC optimized my little program to just output a constant value, since it wasn't depending on any user input or source of randomness? Will it do the same in my real big program? Are there any ways to force it to actually run the functions?

Comment: Note that there's no need to try a different host -- to see the effect of different timezones, just set the TZ environment variable:  `TZ=GMT ./a.out` will run your program in the GMT timezone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't initialize every field of `tm_date`, like `tm_isdst`, so some of the fields have unpredictable values. Fix the bug and the mystery will go away.

Answer (score 4):

> Has GCC optimized my little program to just output a constant value, since it wasn't depending on any user input or source of randomness?

If you think your variable is not updating when you think it should be, then you can either turn off optimizations and try it, or make the variable `volatile`:

Example:

```
int count = 0;    
while(count == 0);
```

Here the compiler optimizes by turning off checking the value of `count` every time it executes the `while` statement. But the `count` variable may be updated by other external factors.

Hence, to force the compiler to disable optimization at this point, we declare `count` to be `volatile`.